# Value for IDENT_CURRENT() when using "insert into select IDENT_CURRENT()" and "insert into select IDENT_CURRENT() from table"

Tags: sql-server, select, identity

I am using sql server and got a question when using IDENT_CURRENT().

My table is like this:

ID, Ori-ID, Company, Other Info

1 , 1     , 1000001, xxx1

2 , 1     , 1000001, xxx2

3 , 3     , 1000002, yyy1

4 , 1,    , 1000001, xxx3

...

"ID" is defined as bigint indentity and "Ori-ID" is also bigint but keeps 1st ID of same company.
Each time when there is any changing, a new record with different ID but same Ori-ID will be created.(for example we can see company 100001 in 3 records are all with Ori-ID 1)
So we could check the history of the company by checking same Ori-ID.

After I ran below steps, the result is not like what I expected and I would like to know the mechanism and how the result is returned:

> Step 1:
> Run "select IDENT_CURRENT('My Table')"

this will returns "5".

> Step 2:
> Run "Insert into My table select IDENT_CURRENT('My Table'), '100003','AAA';"

I could get result like below:
ID, Ori-ID, Company, Other Info
6 , 6     , 100003 , AAA

> Step 3:
> Run "Insert into My table select IDENT_CURRENT('My Table'), '100004',*Other Table.some item* **from Other Table**;"

I could get result like below:
ID, Ori-ID, Company, Other Info
7 , 6     , 100004 , (other items)

For Step 3, I suppose I could get result like this:
ID, Ori-ID, Company, Other Info
7 , **7**     , 100004 , (other items)

Ori-ID with "7" is my expected result. To make it correct I can use "Insert into My table select IDENT_CURRENT('My Table')**+1**, '100004',Other Table.some item from Other Table;" instead, but I'd like to know the why it returns a different result.

It seems IDENT_CURRENT('My Table') changes with or without from clause.
Could any body kindly tell me the reason fot this?

Comment: Why are you using `IDENT_CURRENT` for an `INSERT` in the first place. It isn't scope limited.

Comment: Each time a record for new company is created, I need to get the ID for Ori-ID. As I tried, because ID is generated automatically so in insert clause I only added 3 cols Ori-ID, Company and other info. Of cource for Ori-ID I can update it latter but i tried to make it simple.

Comment: But why `IDENT_CURRENT` and not `SCOPE_IDENTITY`? But why would you *not* expect a different value for your 2 `SELECT` statements? In each you are `INSERT`ing a row into `MyTable`, and then getting the value of `IDENT_CURRENT` for said table; of course the value with have increased. If I ask you to count how many marbles are in a bag, and then i add another to it, and ask you to count again, if you get the same number you've miscounted.

Comment: You're asking why the value of an auto incrementing ID value is automatically incrementing after an insert... I don't understand your question, how could it do anything else?

Comment: @Larnu: I got some other tables also with identity. As my understanding when using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), I could get value for last update table but maybe not the one i am using. Reg your example, I dont understand. Lets say at first, select IDENT_CURRENT() is 4, then I run 1st insert and I got result with ID equals to 5 and Ori-ID equals to 5. Now I run select IDENT_CURRENT() again and it should shows 5 for now. Then I run 2nd insert and I got result ID with 6 but Ori-ID sill 5. How could it be that we have ID equals to Ori-ID and ID not equals to Ord-ID.

Comment: @Stu: My explanation was bad... when recored of new company is created i need to encure that Ori-ID equals to ID but with or without from clause, Ori-ID may equals to ID or may equals to ID+1. The reason why it differs is what I want to know.

Comment: Take a step back and explain the problem you are *really* trying to solve her, @sola . [edit] your question asit seems we have an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) here

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I edited my question and hope it could be clear this time.